# @BatchSize & Spring Boot 3: unexpected null in select query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

We often used in the project @BatchSize for resolve N+1 problem.

Example: Person -> Address (@OneToOne association)

And before migration to Spring Boot 3 @BatchSize(size = 10) means

if I get 20 Persons hibernate makes 2 queries (by first 10 person ids, by second 10 person ids)

if I get 3 Persons query looks like  `select ... where personId IN (id1, id2, id3)`.

But after migration  I suppose property `size` is used as default size not  maximum batch size for batch fetching. And now the second query looks like `select ... where personId IN (id1, id2, id3, null, null, null, null, null, null)`.

How could it be fixed? To return to previous query view?

Comment: I _think_ this is to help DB cache prepared statements, see https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-in-list-padding/ (jOOQ, not JPA, but explains well that _IN-list padding_ concept).

Answer (score 1):

According to your description you are affected by [this Hibernate issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16005) which is also caused by [this Hiberante issue.](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16043)

As described there

> Hibernate 6.1.6 generated queries 2 more and binded data in each query
> were article-id that had empty tag list. **And the values in IN clause
> at the last query was always generated as much as the size of
> @BatchSize.**

According to the ticket upgrading to Hibernate version `6.1.7` or `6.2.0.CR2` should eliminate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate 5 and later versions, the @BatchSize annotation has changed its behavior, and the size attribute is used as a hint for the JDBC batch size, not the maximum size for batch fetching. This can lead to the behavior you've described where the second query includes null placeholders.

If you want to revert to the previous behavior where the batch size is used for controlling the maximum number of entities fetched in a batch, you can use the @org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize annotation from the Hibernate specific annotations package.

```js
import org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize;

@Entity
public class Person {
    // Your other annotations...

    @BatchSize(size = 10)
    @OneToOne
    private Address address;

    // Other fields and methods...
}
```

In this example, @BatchSize(size = 10) is used with @org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize to indicate that when fetching the Address associated with a Person, Hibernate should use batch fetching with a maximum size of 10.

By using the Hibernate-specific @org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize annotation, you can retain the previous behavior you had before migrating to Spring Boot 3. This way, the size attribute will again control the maximum number of entities fetched in a batch, helping to avoid the inclusion of unnecessary null placeholders in the generated SQL queries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I told before about behavior `@org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize`, you propose to use it, but we have already used it and have problem.

Comment: also we use it on class level. I mean `@BatchSize public class Address`, due to usage on method level don't help to avoid N+1 problem with `@OneToOne` association.